# Django model field clashes with other model field that doesn't exist?

Tags: python, django

I'm getting this error:

```
ERRORS:
pokollector.CustomPokemon.poke_id: (models.E006) The field 'poke_id' clashes with the field 'poke_id' from model 'pokollector.pokemon'.
```

Here's the relevant code:

```
class Pokemon(models.Model):
    poke_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    poke_type = models.ManyToManyField(PokeType)
    evolves_from = False
    evolves_into = False
    gen_added = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[min(1), max(gen)])

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Pokemon'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.poke_name


class CustomPokemon(Pokemon):
    #Add name and level for user's specific Pokemon
    poke_id = models.ForeignKey(Pokemon, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        related_name='poke_id', verbose_name='Pokemon ID')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    level = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    #add owner attr

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Custom Pokemon'

    def save(self):
        if not self.name:
            self.name = self.poke_name
        super().save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

As you can see, I have two models, one of which inherits from the other. The error in question relates to the `poke_id` field in `CustomPokemon`. I thought this might be some weird conflict caused by inheritance, but if I change the field name to `pokemon_id`, the issue is resolved.

While a workaround like that gets my code running, I'm curious what the underlying principle is here; Why does the exact same code run after adding those three letters?

Comment: It does, since `CustomPokemon` inherits from `Pokemon`, it also inherits the `related_name` of the field, since that is the name of the field in *reverse*.

Answer (score 1):

The [**`related_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) is the name of the relation in *reverse*. So it access the related `CustomPokemon` objects for a given `Pokemon`. This thus means that `Pokemon` has an "impliciet field" if you want that is here named `poke_id`. Since `CustomPokemon` inherits from `Pokemon`, there are now two `poke_id` fields, hence the clash.

It however does not make much sense to specify `related_name='poke_id'. You can for example use` custompokemons` instead:

```
class CustomPokemon(Pokemon):
    poke_id = models.ForeignKey(
        Pokemon,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        related_name='custompokemons',
        verbose_name='Pokemon ID'
    )
    # …
```

---

> **Note**: Normally one does not add a suffix `_id` to a `ForeignKey` field, since Django
> will automatically add a "twin" field with an `_id` suffix. Therefore it should
> be `pokemon`, instead of <s>`poke_id`</s>.

Comment: Ok I think I understand. When I created a ForeignKey relationship, the `Pokemon` model was given a hidden field called `poke_id`, which is referenced by the related_name field in `CustomPokemon`. When `CustomPokemon` inherited from `Pokemon`, it also inherited the `poke_id` field (as determined by the `related_field`), which it already had and hence the clash. Is that the gist of it?